# Print multiple rows in AWK

Tags: html, awk, html-table

I want to print names in multiple rows in AWK. Currently, I am able to print 3 rows and 3 columns are both put in an HTML table. What I want is to be able to print the indefinite number of rows depending on the number of my input items without having to specify the exact number of rows to print.

For example, I want to print the following names in 3 columns but the number of the rows depends on the number of names. If the number of names is 33 then I will have 3 columns and 11 rows. Help me do it, in AWK.
The names:

```
Kiss Roland
Nagy jolan
Lisztes Tibor
Feher aNDRas
Korma Maria
Akarki Jack
KOVACS PETER
Kiss Roland
Nagy jolan
Lisztes Tibor
Feher aNDRas
Korma Maria
Akarki Jack
KOVACS PETER
Kiss Roland
Nagy jolan
Lisztes Tibor
Feher aNDRas
Korma Maria
Akarki Jack
KOVACS PETER
Kiss Roland
Nagy jolan
Lisztes Tibor
Feher aNDRas
Korma Maria
Akarki Jack
```

So far I have this AWK code. It capitalizes the names as necessary and prints them in 3 columns. Now I need the rows to be as many and not just 3 as currently. Here is the code:

```
BEGIN{
    FS=OFS=" ";
  print "<html>" ORS "<title>" ORS "Hello World" ORS "</title>";
  print "<head>" ORS "<style>" ORS "table, th, td {" ORS "  border: 1px solid black;" ORS "}" ORS "</style>";
  print "</style>" ORS "<body>" ORS "<table>";
}{
    s=tolower($0);
    split (s, letters, " ");
    array[arraylen++] = toupper( substr( letters[1], 1, 1 )  ) substr( letters[1], 2 ) " " toupper( substr( letters[2], 1, 1 )  ) substr( letters[2], 2 );
    up=toupper(substr(s,1,1));
    small=tolower(substr(s,1,1));
    as=sub(/small/, up, s);
}

END {
    columns = 3;
    print "<table>";
    for (rows = 0; rows < columns; rows++) {
        printf "<tr>";
        for (cell = rows; cell <= rows + 2*columns; cell += columns) {
            printf "<td>%s</td> ", array[cell];
        }
        print "</tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";
}
```

Currently, it outputs into this HTML file with just 3 rows and 3 columns: I hope you understand that I need the rows to be many and not just 3.

```
<html>
<title>
Hello World
</title>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</style>
<body>
<table>
<table>
<tr><td>Kovacs Peter</td> <td>Lisztes Tibor</td> <td>Akarki Jack</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Kiss Roland</td> <td>Feher Andras</td> <td>Kovacs Peter</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Nagy Jolan</td> <td>Korma Maria</td> <td>Kiss Roland</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

this will create the body of the table, add the header and footer text to this

```
pr -3ts$'\t' file | sed 's ^ <tr><td> ;s \t </td><td> g;s $ </td></tr> '

<tr><td>Kiss Roland</td><td>Lisztes Tibor</td><td>Korma Maria</td></tr>
<tr><td>Nagy jolan</td><td>Feher aNDRas</td><td>Akarki Jack</td></tr>
<tr><td>Lisztes Tibor</td><td>Korma Maria</td><td>KOVACS PETER</td></tr>
<tr><td>Feher aNDRas</td><td>Akarki Jack</td><td>Kiss Roland</td></tr>
<tr><td>Korma Maria</td><td>KOVACS PETER</td><td>Nagy jolan</td></tr>
<tr><td>Akarki Jack</td><td>Kiss Roland</td><td>Lisztes Tibor</td></tr>
<tr><td>KOVACS PETER</td><td>Nagy jolan</td><td>Feher aNDRas</td></tr>
<tr><td>Kiss Roland</td><td>Lisztes Tibor</td><td>Korma Maria</td></tr>
<tr><td>Nagy jolan</td><td>Feher aNDRas</td><td>Akarki Jack</td></tr>
```

if you want rows first instead

```
$ pr -3ats$'\t' file | sed 's ^ <tr><td> ;s \t </td><td> g;s $ </td></tr> '

<tr><td>Kiss Roland</td><td>Nagy jolan</td><td>Lisztes Tibor</td></tr>
<tr><td>Feher aNDRas</td><td>Korma Maria</td><td>Akarki Jack</td></tr>
<tr><td>KOVACS PETER</td><td>Kiss Roland</td><td>Nagy jolan</td></tr>
<tr><td>Lisztes Tibor</td><td>Feher aNDRas</td><td>Korma Maria</td></tr>
<tr><td>Akarki Jack</td><td>KOVACS PETER</td><td>Kiss Roland</td></tr>
<tr><td>Nagy jolan</td><td>Lisztes Tibor</td><td>Feher aNDRas</td></tr>
<tr><td>Korma Maria</td><td>Akarki Jack</td><td>KOVACS PETER</td></tr>
<tr><td>Kiss Roland</td><td>Nagy jolan</td><td>Lisztes Tibor</td></tr>
<tr><td>Feher aNDRas</td><td>Korma Maria</td><td>Akarki Jack</td></tr>
```